# Table is not getting updated through mysqli_query insert

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Below is my `html` form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
             Registration
        </title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form action="backreg.php" method="post">
          user id:<input type="text" name="rid"><br>
          fname:<input type="text" name="rname"><br>
          gender:
          <select name="rgen">
              <option value="male">male</option>
              <option value="female">female</option>
          </select><br>
          dob:<input type="text" name="rdob"><br>
          mobile:<input type="text" name="rmob"><br>
          PASSWORD:<input type="password" name="rpwd">
          <input type="submit" name="rsubmit" value="register">
     </form>

     <a href="index2.php" >already registered ?</a >
   </body>
</html>
```

The corresponding `php` code (`backreg.php`) to capture the values entered in the above form is below:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'root', '', 'manideep_db');
if(isset($_POST['rsubmit'] ))
{
$id=$_POST['rid'];
$name=$_POST['rname'];
$gender=$_POST['rgen'];
$dob=$_POST['rdob'];
$mobile=$_POST['rmob'];
$password=$_POST['rpwd'];
$run=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `table_1` (`rid`, `rname`, `rgen`, `rdob`,'rmob','rpwd')VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$gender', '$dob','$mobile','$password')");
if($run)
{
  header('Location: index2.php');
}
echo "error";
}
?>
```

`manideep_db` is my database name. `table_1` is a table inside the `db` which contains the `id`, `name`, `dob`, `gender`, `mobile` and `password` fields. After filling the form and submitting, I'm getting output `error` instead of page getting redirected to `index2.php`. Please suggest what is going wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, **don't** store passwords in plain text, use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and secondly, you're wide open to [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You'll also find it more useful, while debugging, to actually output *what* the error is (using [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)) rather than just the word "error". You might also want to add `die()` just after that `header()`.

Comment: is rid field in table_1 is of auto increment type ?

Comment: rid field is not of auto increment type. Do I have to change it?

Comment: I have used mysqli_error and it has displayed this message 
Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rmob','rpwd') VALUES ('15', 'mani', 'male', '22-06-1995','' at line 1

Comment: It helped. Thank you so much for your inputs. mysqli_error() did a great help.